# Issues with WDI, wb_stats SP.POP.TOTL indicator in r

Tags: r

I am using WDI to get population data from `SP.POP.TOTL` indicator and this was working from past few weeks but looks like there are some issues now with this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(WDI)


country_stats <- WDI::WDI(country = 'all', 
          indicator = c(pop_2019 = "SP.POP.TOTL", 
                        gdpPerCap_2019 = "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD"), 
          start = 2019, end = 2019, extra = TRUE) %>% 
   as_tibble()
```

**Error:**

> Error in WDI::WDI(country = "all", indicator = c(pop_2019 = "SP.POP.TOTL", : The following indicators could not be downloaded: SP.POP.TOTL, NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD. Please make sure that you are running the latest version of the `WDI` package, and that the arguments you are using in the `WDI()` function are valid. Sometimes, downloads will suddenly stop working, even if nothing has changed in the R code of the WDI package. ("The same WDI package version worked yesterday!") In those cases, the problem is almost certainly related to the World Bank servers or to your internet connection. You can check if the World Bank web API is currently serving the indicator(s) of interest by typing a URL of this form in your web browser: https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/country/all/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?format=json&date=1960:2020&per_page=32500&page=1

I have reinstalled the package but still same issue.